# how to save nested references entities using jpa?

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

Report can have many groups.
group can have subgroups.

Requirement is to clone the data which will be having new references in a generic way.
Even after setting parent and report in ReportGroups manually(Bi Directional data). References keys are still saved as null

eg.
Report
[image: Report]

ReportGroups

[image: Report Group]

code:
public class Report {

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "report", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Where(clause = "parent_group_id is null")
    private List<ReportGroups> reportGroups;

    public static Report cloneEntity( Report from) {
      Report to = Report.builder()
            .code(from.getCode())
            .build();
     ​to.setReportGroups(ReportGroups.cloneReportGroups(from.getReportGroups(),to));
    
    return to;
}
}​ ​
```

//

```
public class ReportGroups {
    ​ ​
    @Id
​   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
​   @Column(name = "id")
​   private Long id;​

    @Column
    private String code;
​
    @ManyToOne
​   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_group_id")
​   private ReportGroups parent;​ 
​
    @ManyToOne
​   @JoinColumn(name = "report_id")
​   private Report report;​ ​ 
​
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
​   private List<ReportGroups> subGroups;

    public static ReportGroups cloneEntity(ReportGroups from) {
        ReportGroups to = ReportGroups.builder().code(from.getCode()).build();
        to.setSubGroups(cloneReportGroups(to, from.getSubGroups()));

        return to;
    }

    public static List<ReportGroups> cloneReportGroups(ReportGroups parentGroup, List<ReportGroups> reportGroups) {

        if (reportGroups == null || reportGroups.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        List<ReportGroups> clone = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ReportGroups r : reportGroups) {
            r.setParent(r);
            clone.add(cloneEntity(r));
        }
        parentGroup.setSubGroups(clone);

        return clone;

    }

    public static List<ReportGroups> cloneReportGroups(List<ReportGroups> reportGroups, Report to) {

        if (reportGroups == null || reportGroups.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        List<ReportGroups> clone = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ReportGroups r : reportGroups) {
            r.setReport(to);
            clone.add(cloneEntity(r));
        }
        return clone;
    }

    ​
}

 @Service
public class ReportService {
    @Autowired
    private ReportRepository repository;

    public Report cloneReport(Long id) {

        Report report = repository.findById(id);
        Report newReport = Report.cloneEntity(report);
        newReport = repository.save(newReport);
        return newReport;

     }
}

 @Repository
 public interface ReportRepository extends JpaRepository<Report, Long> {
      Report findById(Long id);

 }
```

The newReport saved is having references as null instead of new reference id to maintain the hierarchy relation(within and across tables)

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate please a bit more on what you are asking? Enrich your question with example code not only the entities but also what you have tried so far e.g. services or repositories for saving?

Comment: Updated the question for your reference